# Interactions with Background being blocked by Div over the background

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, z-index, particles.js

I am using [Particles.js](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js) on the background. I have div layer over the canvas which contains text and images.

This div blocks the interactions with the background killing the experience. Is there a way to make sure the div allows the interactions through it with the background. Above and below the Div the interactions work well as the content is vertically centered.

[Demo Link](http://creo.mink7.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this css in your code. ( line no. 19)

```
#hero-unit .particles-js-canvas-el {
    z-index: -1 !important;
}
```

Change it to

```
#hero-unit .particles-js-canvas-el {
    z-index: 1 !important;
}
```

and

```
#hero-unit #hero-wrapper {
    z-index: 1!important;
}
```

**FIX to make the the interaction through the text or next to it**

wrap the divs in seperate `.col-md-9` `rows`

```
<div class="row">
    <!--  first row -->
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <img class="hero-logo hidden-xs" src="http://creo.mink7.com/wp-content/themes/creo/images/logo-home.png" alt="">
        <h1 class="head">Together we can Make a universe of smart innovations for a Better tomorrow</h1> 
    </div>

    <!--  second row -->
    <div class="col-md-9 newsletter">
        <div id="frontpage-mailchimp">
            <h4>Join the Community of Makers</h4>

            <!-- MailChimp for WordPress v3.0.10 - https://wordpress.org/plugins/mailchimp-for-wp/ -->
            <form id="mc4wp-form-1" class="mc4wp-form mc4wp-form-114" method="post" data-id="114" data-name="Join us in making things better">
                <!--  mailchimp stuffs -->
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and finally, this css

```
 #hero-wrapper .col-md-9{
        z-index: 1; // reduce the default z-index for div
    } 

#hero-wrapper .col-md-9.newsletter{
    z-index: 9999; // increase the z-index for newletter div only
 }
```

Comment: when i do that i can not enter the email address into the form.

Comment: updated the answer. by adding those codes, you can now access email form as well.

Comment: thanks. there is no way we can may the interaction through the text or next to it?

Comment: @HarshaMV found a fix :)